# What's the related syscall for GUI programing on x86-64(linux)?

Tags: linux, user-interface, system-calls

Anyone knows which syscall is for GUI programing so that we can draw various pictures on the screen?

I don't find one [here](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/)..

GUI needs kernel support,right?

Comment: The Linux kernel doesn't know about graphics output. An X server is responsible for managing the display on Linux. Your best option is to use a GUI programming framework like Qt, GTK+, wxWidgets or Tk, depending on your programming language and needs.

Answer (score 5):

You draw on the screen by talking the X11 protocol to the system's Xserver. (The system calls involved are the usual ones for talking over a socket, so they're not informative.) Usually you use a library to do that. The usual basic library to use is the X11 library (libX11) and that is usually wrapped by a toolkit library like GTK or Qt (or wxWindows or Tk or …). There are low level libraries too (xcb, which is a thinner layer over the X protocol) and higher level libraries as well (Gnome, KDE). You can also use OpenGL libraries, which is a whole different approach.

There are whole shelves of books on how to do this.

---

The Xserver itself uses memory mapped devices, and it talks at a very low level to the graphics hardware. It's not a hugely higher level thing than a graphics driver, and it is a very highly privileged process. (If you're comparing with Windows, you need to be aware that the exact levels that things are split at is different, *but* the level of libX11 is fairly similar to much of the Win API.)

Comment: @x86: Short answer: it's complicated and very device specific. RTFSource of the Xserver if you care, but I've never really wanted to learn that much detail.